# vuejs filter is not function

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

Вообщем пишу приложение на vuejs и столкнулся с такой проблемой не могу правильно вытащить данные из переменной.

Вот код:

```
<tbody v-if="currencies !== null && currenciesUser !== null">
  <tr v-for="currencyItem in currenciesUser" :key="currencyItem.id">
    <td>{{ $t(currencyItem.Name) }}</td>
    <td v-if="currencyItem.CharCode === 'RUB'">
      {{ new Intl.NumberFormat('ru-RU', { style: 'currency', currency: 'RUB',
        minimumSignificantDigits: 3 }).format(1) }}
    </td>
    <td v-else>
      {{ new Intl.NumberFormat(currencyItem.locale, { style: 'currency', currency: currencyItem.CharCode, minimumSignificantDigits: 3 }).format(currencies.Valute.filter(item => item.CharCode === currencyItem.CharCode).Value) }}
    </td>
    <td>{{ $moment(currencies.Date).format('DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm') }}</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Данный получаю вот так:

```
computed: {
  currencies () {
    return this.$store.getters.currencies
  },
  currenciesUser () {
    return this.$store.getters.currenciesUser
  }
}
```

При запуске получаю вот это:

```
TypeError: _vm.currencies.Valute.filter is not a function
```

Соответственно, что нечего не выводиться.
Как это победить??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вообщем решилось всё довольно просто.

```
{{ new Intl.NumberFormat(currencyItem.locale, { style: 'currency', currency: currencyItem.CharCode, minimumSignificantDigits: 3 }).format(currencies.Valute[currencyItem.CharCode].Value) }}
```

Вот так работает, хотя `Valute` это тоже объект